# Using the same Plug-in for multiple purposes in leaflet

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw, turfjs

I am trying to use the leaflet-draw tool for two different things:

1. as a "regular" tool to create new geometries
2. if I draw a line, I perform some calculations with turf.js, giving me points nearby.

I've set up two individual draw controls for each purpose. For the second, I have all but the draw:polyline disabled. The problem: I save my elements with the

```
map.on('draw:created', function(){...});
```

"command". But this way I (or the eventhandler, respectively :)) cant differentiate, if the line was drawn with the first or the second button. So basically i can use the draw tool either for one thing or the other. Is there a way where I can use the same tool for different applications on the same map?

Thanks for any hints or work arounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative would be to use [Leaflet-Geoman](https://github.com/geoman-io/leaflet-geoman) instead of Leaflet-Draw.

There you can create copies of Draw instances and add them a new shape name:

```
// copy a rectangle and customize its name, block, title and actions
map.pm.Toolbar.copyDrawControl('Polygon', {
  name: 'PolygonCopy',
  block: 'custom',
  title: 'Display text on hover button',
  actions: ['cancel', 'removeLastVertex', 'finish'],
});
```

And then you can check the shape name in the create event:

```
// listen to when a new layer is created
map.on('pm:create', function(e) {
  console.log(e)
  if(e.shape === 'Polygon'){
    alert('Original Polygon')
  }else if(e.shape === 'PolygonCopy'){
    alert('Copy Polygon')
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/r0sm9auo/